# Unending While loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

I cannot get my while loop inf the getClasses function to end when it is supposed to. Both getNum and counter are set as integers. I have also tried to do `while True` and an if statement to see if that would help, yet that just gives me an infinite loop. I know that this is a simple problem, yet I cannot figure out what it is that I am doing wrong. Please help.

```
def getNum():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(raw_input("How many classes do you have:\n")) #Asks the user for the number of classes he/she has.
            break
        except:
            print("Input must be a number")
    return num

def getGrades(): #Gets the grades from the user
    counter2 = 1
    global grades
    if counter2 <= getNum: #If the 2nd counter is less than or equa to the number of classes...
        while True:
            try:
                grades = int(raw_input("What is the grade for class %s:\n" %counter2)) #Asks the user what their grades are for 'counter' class.
                counter2 += 1 #...increase the 2nd counter by 1
                break
            except:
                print("Input must be a number")
     return grades

def getClasses(): #Gets the user's classes
    counter = 1
    getNum()
    while counter <= getNum: #If the counter is less than or equal to the number of classes...
        classes = str(raw_input("Class %s is what:\n" %counter)) #Asks the user what their 'counter' class is.
        subjects[classes] = getGrades()
        counter += 1 #...increase the counter by 1 
    return subjects
```

Comment: When is it supposed to end?  What is getNum?

Comment: `counter2 <= getNum` and `getNum()`? It can't be both an integer and a function... this code likely doesn't work at all.

Comment: What is getNum???

Comment: getNum function should return an integer.

Comment: What is the value returning from your getNum() function? The while loop iterates for the getNum() times.

Answer (score 0):

line 4, You mean this ?

```
if counter2 <= getNum() :
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the exception after the except clause. In this case a ValueError.

> If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of
>   the clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named
>   after the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then
>   execution continues after the try statement.

source
 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

```
def getGrades():
    while True:
        try:
           grades = int(input())
           break
        except ValueError:
           print("Please enter digits only")
    return grades
getGrades()
```